# Rails 3.2.12 uninitialized constant error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've been beating my head against my desk all afternoon trying to get past an uninitialized constant error, but can't seem to get beyond it. I have the following models:

sub_award.rb

```
class SubAward < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sub_awards_colleges, foreign_key: [:award_id, :sub_id]
  has_many :colleges, through: :sub_awards_colleges
end
```

sub_awards_colleges.rb

```
class SubAwardsCollege < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sub_award, foreign_key: [:award_id, :sub_id]
  belongs_to :college
end
```

colleges.rb

```
class College < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sub_awards_colleges, foreign_key: [:award_id, :sub_id]
  has_many :sub_awards, through: :sub_awards_colleges
end
```

When I attempt to call `sub_award.colleges` from my view I get the error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant SubAward::SubAwardsCollege)
```

I believe I have followed all the proper rails conventions and I have other associations within the sub_award model that I set up the same and are working fine. The tables look like (unrelated attribute omitted):

```
mysql> DESCRIBE sub_awards_colleges;
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| award_id   | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sub_id     | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| college_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
mysql> DESCRIBE sub_awards;
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| award_id                 | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| sub_id                   | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
mysql> DESCRIBE colleges;
+-------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                   | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                      | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
```

Any help is appreciated and please let me know if you'd like me to provide more information. Thanks!

Comment: In what context are you calling `sub_award.colleges`?

Comment: sub_award.colleges is being classed from a view template

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed to place your sub_awards_colleges.rb file in app/models ! 
I had a similar problem once.
Also why are award_id ans sub_id columns in sub_awards_colleges, As far as I guess, you have a mapping table which should map it to colleges. and there is no use of college_id in mapping, all the mapping is based of award_id and sub_id. This is pretty confusing. You might want to have a look at your mappings once again.

Comment: the SubAward model uses a composite primary key comprised of award_id and sub_id so both those are needed in the SubAwardsCollege model to map back to the SubAward model. The college_id field is used to map to the College model. And I've verified that the sub_awards_colleges.rb file is located in app/models

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue, but I'm still not entirely sure what the problem was. To solve I blew away the existing sub_awards_college.rb file. I then created a new migration to drop the sub_awards_colleges table and re-create it and generated a fresh sub_awards_college.rb model. I re-populated the sub_awards_college.rb file with my associations:

```
belongs_to :sub_award, foreign_key: [:award_id, :sub_id]
belongs_to :college, class_name: "College"
```

adding the class_name option (although it shouldn't be necessary according to conventions) and also added additional parameters to the sub_award.rb associations so it read as:

```
has_many :sub_awards_colleges, foreign_key: [:award_id, :sub_id], source: :sub_awards_colleges, class_name: "SubAwardsCollege"
has_many :colleges, through: :sub_awards_colleges, after_add: :invalidate_matching, after_remove: :invalidate_matching, source: :college, class_name: "College"
```

again, shouldn't be necessary according to conventions, but restarted my app and it's now working. So not exactly sure what my problem was, maybe there was something hokey in the database regarding how my tables were set up so they weren't aligning properly with the models, but it's working now and thank you for taking the time to review and provide comments.